# How do I reduce/remove space between list items in my R Markdown code?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

Okay, so I am knitting my R Markdown to a Word document and want to remove the whitespace available between the list items as much as possible.

The code I'm using is :

```
- The first line.
- The second line.
- The third line.
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably depends on the style for item lists in the Word document template that is used implicitly by `knitr`

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: adding to what user101089  said, you can actually make a word doc template to what you want, and then feed the template to Rmarkdown and have it mold to the word document.

Comment: The key is to use a `reference_docx: my-styles.docx` in the header. See: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with CSS inside Rmarkdown! just add a CSS chunk and you can control the body of text, or any other desired text.

````
---
title: "Rmarkdown page"
output: html_document
---

```{css echo = FALSE}
body {line-height: 5;}
```

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
````

[image]

````
---
title: "Rmarkdown page"
output: html_document
---

```{css echo = FALSE}
body {line-height: .8;}
```

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
````

[image]

Comment: Nope, it did not work. It works only when I knit it into an HTML file.